# MongoDB Node JS Driver find toArray getting the Object Id in different format

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get all documents from a collection as follows:

```
var server = "localhost";
var port   = 27017; 
var dbName = "myNewCreation";
var mongodb          = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var connString = "mongodb://"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName;

mongoClient.connect(connString, function(err, db) {
    console.dir(err);
    if(!err) {
        var collectionName = "employee";
        //get Documents
        db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
          console.dir(err);
          console.dir(docs);
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("Mongo DB could not be connected");
        process.exit(0);
    }

});
```

I am getting the results correctly, but the output of the Object ID is in some machine format as follows:

```
[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'VX%\u000fÜÏ¢6©ø' },
    empName: 'riyke',
    Dob: '20-31-2300',
    salary: '7000' } ]
```

How to get the Object ID properly in human readable form?

I found the solution and it is working fine, I am just updating my question with answer:

Use toString or toHexString methods as follows:

```
var server = "localhost";
    var port   = 27017; 
    var dbName = "myNewCreation";
    var mongodb          = require('mongodb');
    var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var connString = "mongodb://"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName;

    mongoClient.connect(connString, function(err, db) {
        console.dir(err);
        if(!err) {
            var collectionName = "employee";
            //get Documents
            db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
              console.dir(err);
              console.dir(docs);
              consolde.dir(docs[0]._id.toString());
              consolde.dir(docs[0]._id.toHexString());      
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("Mongo DB could not be connected");
            process.exit(0);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `valueOf()` method , `ObjectId.valueOf()` it will return hex string

Comment: ObjectId.valueOf() this is a mongo shell command https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/ As per the question i want to do it using the Node JS Driver for MongoDB